# Can't use "which mysql" in zsh, but in bash work

Tags: mysql, bash, ubuntu, zsh

After Upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and install mysql server 5.5, I Can't use "which mysql" in zsh, but in bash work!!
Here is my echos:

```
    ZSH:
    $ whereis mysql
    mysql: /usr/bin/mysql /etc/mysql /usr/lib/mysql /usr/bin/X11/mysql /usr/share/mysql /usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.g

    $ which mysql
    mysql: aliased to nocorrect mysql

    $ alias
    ...
    ...
    mysql='nocorrect mysql'
    ...
    ...
```

---

```
    BASH:
    $ whereis mysql
    mysql: /usr/bin/mysql /etc/mysql /usr/lib/mysql /usr/bin/X11/mysql /usr/share/mysql /usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.g

    $ which mysql
    /usr/bin/mysql
```

Comment: Check the output of `alias`: it looks like Ubuntu has installed-but-disabled fancy command line completion for mysql, hence the `nocorrect`.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Please check the updates. It seems like that I use the [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/lib/correction.zsh).

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10525/3929 , I'd be inclined to flag this as a duplicate of that?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Thank you very much. "type -a" works for me. It's an useful trick.

Comment: To force path lookup you have to use `whence -p mysql`. Note that it will lookup path also for shell built-ins (like `whence -p echo` will output `/bin/echo`, but `which echo` outputs `echo: shell built-in command`) and shell functions, so it will say what will be launched when you do `command mysql`, but not when you do just `mysql`.